# G105 Keyboard, script to control backlight (Win8)

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I have stumbled into kind of an unusual problem. I have a logitech g105 keyboard with backlighting (pictured below).

[image]

It's a nice keyboard and I'm quite happy with it.
The software provided by logitech works well for recording the custom keys, macros, etc.

There is no option in the software to toggle the backlight. (there is a button on the keyboard itself for this) but I am wondering if there is possibly a way to enable/disable this lighting with just a script or maybe a batch file?

It would be nice if I could find a method to 'flash' the background light once or twice to alert me of something. (right now I'm using sounds for alerts.) I thought maybe disabling/enabling the whole keyboard really quickly would have the desired effect but that didn't work.

I really have no idea where to even begin with this. Is this even possible? Help is always appreciated, thanks in advance.